# C# - TextLogger

Tags: c#

My English isn't that good.

I try to make a TextLogger, for example:
if I have two different arrays:

```
string[] array1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
string[] array2 = {"y", "c", "h", "f"}
```

and I have the char "c" in both of the arrays, then both of the char "c" should be removed.

Output:
a, b, d, h, y, f

this is what I managed to do so far:

```
string[] array1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
string[] array2 = {"y", "c", "h", "f"}
for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
    if(array1[i] == array2[i])
    {

    }
}
```

edit(sorry for keep changing my question):

and how I can do it with this:

```
ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList();
array1.Add("a");
array1.Add("b");
array1.Add("c");
array1.Add("d");

ArrayList array2 = new ArrayList();
array1.Add("y");
array1.Add("c");
array1.Add("h");
array1.Add("f");
```

Comment: Array is immutable class, you can't change it! But you can create a new array

Comment: can you provide more context and some example input and expected output.

Comment: @Marusyk: .NET arrays are *not* immutable. Their length cannot be changed, but existing elements can be replaced.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes, replaced but not removed. Did you see the desired output?

Comment: I know that with:
ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList();

I can do array1.Remove()

Comment: @Marusyk: The desired output is irrelevant. "immutable" means no changes at all are possible, which is not true.

Comment: @Daniel do you want the result in a single array?

Comment: What if `array1` contained `"b"` twice? Should `"b"` be removed in that instance?

Comment: no, if array1 contained "b" twice then remove only one line

Answer (score 3):

1- Get common items using [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

2- replace each array by the same array except common items using [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string[] array1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
string[] array2 = { "y", "c", "h", "f" };

var intersect = array1.Intersect(array2); // 1

array1 = array1.Except(intersect).ToArray(); //2
array2 = array2.Except(intersect).ToArray(); //2
```

Edit: to take into account double values as mentioned in the comment:

```
string[] array1 = { "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d" };
string[] array2 = { "y", "b",  "c", "h", "f" };

var grpArray1 = array1.GroupBy(a => a)
                 .Select(grp => new { item = grp.Key, count = grp.Count() });
var grpArray2 = array2.GroupBy(a => a)
                 .Select(grp => new { item = grp.Key, count = grp.Count() });

array1 = grpArray1.Select(a =>
               {
                var bCount = array2.Count(x => x.Equals(a.item));
                return new { item = a.item, finalCount = a.count - bCount };
               })
              .Where(a => a.finalCount > 0)
              .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Repeat(a.item, a.finalCount))
              .ToArray();

array2 = grpArray2.Select(a =>
              {
               var bCount = array1.Count(x => x.Equals(a.item));
               return new { item = a.item, finalCount = a.count - bCount };
              })
             .Where(a => a.finalCount > 0)
             .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Repeat(a.item, a.finalCount))
             .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("-->array1:");
foreach (var item in array1)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

Console.WriteLine("-->array2:");
foreach (var item in array2)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The results:

```
-->array1:
a
b
b
d
-->array2:
y
h
f
```

Answer (score 1):

If if understand your problem correctly, you don't need to change that arrays (array1 and array2) but get a result from both of them.
so, you can solve your problem using the GroupBy method

```
            string[] array1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
            string[] array2 = { "y", "c", "h", "f" };

            var filteredArray = array1.Concat(array2).GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Select(x=>x.Key);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", filteredArray));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

what we can see here, is concat the arrays into 1 list, then group by the chars into groups, and then filter the groups that contain more than 1 element, and in the end revert it into list of chars (instead of list of groups)

**Edit:**

out of the comment about the duplicated "b" inside each of the arrays, i created a new (with little bit more complexity) that works for your case:

```
        string[] array1 = { "a", "b", "b", "c", "d" };
        string[] array2 = { "y", "c", "h", "f" };

        var filteredArray = array1.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Concat(array2.GroupBy(x => x))
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
            .Where(x => x.Count() == 1).SelectMany(x => x.Key);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", filteredArray));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

whats happen there? we group the arrays each for himself, then concat the groups together, and then we group the groups by their keys, and the filter where each group contain more then 1 inner group, and in the end we select the groups keys (in addition it's promise us there is only 1 instance of each char)

Hope that helps!

Comment: What about 3 "b", and more "b"ees ? ^^

Comment: you can put how much "b" that you would like, read the explanation below the code, it's doesn't matter how much instances of a char \ string, there is only different between 1 and more than 1

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should provide you a clear insight about how to perform your task:

```
String[] array1 = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
String[] array2 = new String[] {"y", "c", "h", "f"};

String[] n1 = array1.Where(x => !array2.Contains(x)).ToArray();
String[] n2 = array2.Where(x => !array1.Contains(x)).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Array 1");

foreach (String s in n1)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.WriteLine("\nArray 2");

foreach (String s in n2)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is:

```
Array 1
a
b
d

Array 2
y
h
f
```

and can see a working demo by visiting [this link](http://rextester.com/HNLZ11111). For more information concerning the methods I used in order to accomplish, visit the following links:

- [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumerable.ToArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This likely doesn't handle the duplicate `"b"` issue mentioned in the comments.